# Как записать данные в файл тхт?

Tags: php

Нужно создать скрипт записывающий строку "текст" в файл, который находится на компьютере клиента.

**Добавлено.**

Вот пример моего кода

```
<?

  $file = fopen ("D:/file.txt","a+");
  $str = "Hello, world! \n\r";
  if ( !$file )
  {
    echo("Ошибка открытия файла");
  }
  else
  {
    fputs ( $file, $str);
  }
  fclose ($file);
?>
```

Пишет

> Ошибка открытия файла.

Comment: ндаа... народ мельчает...

Comment: Даже не пытайтесь. Теоретически - есть только один путь - JScript (не JavaScript, а именно JScript), но, во-первых это сработает ТОЛЬКО в ИЕ, а во-вторых - может вообще не сработать из-за настроек безопасности... Так что реализуйте то, что Вам надо с помощью куков.

Answer (score 5):

На компьютере клиента нельзя создавать файлы.

Comment: он уже зарание создан мне нжно вносить туда текстовую информацию

Comment: И записывать нельзя.<br />
Единственное, что могу вам предложить - использовать cookies.
PHP является серверным языком программирования и всё, что он делает - отсылает браузеру готовый HTML код, предварительно обработав сценарий.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ответу, и могу добавить что записывать данные можно в фаил/бд на сервере (ip+время) но уж точно не на компьютер клиента.

Answer (score 3):

PHP скрипты выполняются на стороне сервера, потому создавать, открывать, записывать и т.п. файлы на стороне клиента средствами PHP нельзя.

В вашем примере "D:/file.txt" будет означать, что данный файл сервер будет пытаться открыть на своем диске D, а не у клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос чуть не понял, но вот пример - создание файла с помощью php:

```
<?
  $fp = fopen ("Имя_файла.txt", "w"); 
  fwrite($fp,"текст");
  fclose($fp); 
?>
```

Comment: Не совсем, мне на сайте надо создать функцию, чтобы при заходе на сайт, на локальном диске клиента в файле `D:/Site.txt` записывалася текст к примеру "Был сегодня в ....".

Файл уже заранее создан.

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы при заходе на сайт, на компьютере человека, который зашел, в файле Site.txt записывалась время и дата захода; как взять время и дату, я знаю, а вот, как произвести запись в файл, не знаю.

Comment: А пусть соответствует действительности?

Comment: что соотвецтвует действительности!
я прошу дать код, записи в локальній файл текста! а мне кучу сообщений не по теме вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Никто не даст вашему сайту делать что-то с локальной машиной из-за соображений безопасности.  Ответ однозначен,  так сделать нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сохранить данные на машине клиента, можно воспользоваться предназначенными для этого хранилищами:

- cookie
  `setcookie('last_visited', time());`
- localStorage(sessionStorage, etc)
  `$now = time(); echo "<script>localStorage.last_visited = {$now};</script>";`

Answer (score -1):

Можно ещё вот такой вариант:

```
$f = fopen("file.txt", "a");
fputs($f, "текст или переменная"); 
fclose($f);
```

Comment: Это полный код? Если да, то не работает.

Comment: Вы с путём разберитесь своим! Изначально!

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но с языком пхп, знаком очень слабо, если можно, пример кода, c помощью которого я смогу записывать данные (к примеру, текст "Текст Текст Текст") клиенту в файл, который находится:
`D://Site.txt`

Comment: 1. $f = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "file.txt", "a");
fputs($f, "текст или переменная"); 
fclose($f);

2. не помню, может нужен ещё слеш перед file.txt или нет.

Comment: Ну этот файл на сервере хранится.

Answer (score -1):

1. [Работа с файлами](http://www.php.su/lessons/?lesson_8)
2. [ftp_get](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.ftp-get.html) - загрузка файла с FTP-сервера

Comment: та мне не с фтп надо, а с локального компьютора клиента

Comment: Либо Вы пишете дату/время в файл на сервере и скрипт через ftp_get перегоняет этот файл с сервера в локальный файл, либо без вариантов

Comment: ну с датой я разберусь сам, мне надо код которій будет вписивать мне "Текс1 Текст 2 Текст 3"в фай D://Site.txt
можна пример ?